# How should I interpret this performance standards table?

Tags: strength-training, starting-strength

Starting strength wiki refers to these [strength standard tables](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.html).

Are the values listed there the upper limit for the category, or the lower limit?

In other words, I'm 81Kg and I'm able to [squat](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/SquatStandardsKg.html) 90Kg, am I 'untrained' or 'novice'?

Comment: You would be more like novice, squatting your own body weight is not something an untrained person can do easily.

Comment: Please be aware that these tables are based off of your 1RM (one rep max), not your current work weight in the Starting Strength program. If you don't know your 1RM you can use this [1RM Calculator](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/OneRepMax.html) to estimate it based off of how many reps you can do of your current work weight.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting close to "novice" level, it's not a low/high limit. If you squat 100 kg weighing 82 kg you are a novice according to the chart. But it's completely subjective of course.

Comment: very true, you can't get anything out of charts like that, it